# Way to load all functions in a package in R?

Tags: r, function

I am attempting to take a function and apply it in a slightly different way in my own function. However I keep running into dependency issues, such and such function not found.

This in spite of the fact, that the function itself works just fine only loading rlist.

This is select.list in the rlist package:

```
function (.data, ...) 
{
  args <- set_argnames(dots(...))
  quote <- as.call(c(quote(list), args))
  list.map.internal(.data, quote, parent.frame())
}
```

If I attempt to run this function I get an error that the function set_argnames was not found.

When I go into that function here:

```
function (args, data = args) 
{
  argnames <- getnames(args, character(length(args)))
  indices <- !nzchar(argnames) & vapply(args, is.name, logical(1L))
  argnames[indices] <- as.character(args[indices])
  setnames(data, argnames)
}
```

I run into errors of similar nature.

I have intalled and loaded all package dependecies, LinkingTos,Imports,and even suggesteds. Nothing seems to solve the issue.

Is there a way to load all the dependent functions of a function?

Comment: If you load the function with `library(rlist)` then it should work. But it seems like you are cherry-picking individual functions and trying to weave them into your own workspace and/or personal package. What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: select.list does work fine after loading rlist. I am trying to use select.list within another function. Both my function and select.list have ellipses, which I needed to make an edit to make work. However, there has to be a way to load all dependent functions. How is R using them when I make a direct call to the function and not when I use the source code of the function?

Comment: There is a not-obvious series of search-paths for a loaded package. That is, a package searches for functions first in its own namespace (including unexported functions), then in namespaces of packages it explicitly imports (via its package declaration), then in namespaces of the package that loaded it, etc, until it reaches the global environment. Because `set_argnames` is defined in the same package's namespace, it is found by `list.select` despite not being exported. I suggest http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html as a good reference for this process.

Comment: But I do not know of a way to import just the function you want and all of its dependent functions without excessive parsing and tracking of functions/namespaces. The supported method (`library(rlist)`) is the most straight-forward and the supported method: it handles this process for you. Can you explain why you want to import just that function (and anything that it needs)? Why not the entire package? Are you just trying to keep your namespace "pristine"?

Comment: Why are you copying the source code of these functions?